# Closedness of Bessel vector space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space. A unitary system $\mathcal{U}$ is a subset of the unitary operators acting on  $\mathcal{H}$ which contains the identity operator $I$. A
 vector $\eta\in \mathcal{H}$ is called a Bessel vector for $\mathcal{U}$ if $$\mathcal{U}\eta=\{U\eta;\quad U\in\mathcal{U}\}$$
is  Bessel sequence; that is,
$$\sum_{U\in\mathcal{U}}|\langle f, U\eta\rangle|^2<B\|f\|^2$$ for every $f\in\mathcal{H}$. If $ \mathcal{U}\eta $ is a
Bessel sequence for $\mathcal{H}$, then the vector $\eta$ is called a Bessel vector for $\mathcal{U}$. The set of all Bessel vectors for $\mathcal{U}$ is denoted by $\mathcal{B(U)}$.

My question: Is $\mathcal{B(U)}$ closed with Hilbert space norm?
It seems that $\mathcal{B(U)}$ is not closed with Hilbert space norm. Please give me a counterexample of it.

Comment: I don't thinkt that this space is closed with respect to the Hilbert space norm, since $B$ depends on $\eta$. We may have a convergent sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $B(f_n)$ is divergent.

Comment: @p4sch I agree. Would you give an example?